# SwiftUI multicolor and multipurpose textfield

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Have a problem here, trying to achieve such functionality as on screen shot.
As you can see, there is 2 types of interaction.

1. User can tap on time, like 15 minutes, and a TimePicker will appear. And on weekday - another view will appear.
2. User can tap on purpose and input his own text between 'on' and 'each' words. Like usual, keyboard will appear, cursor appears - user is ready to input his text in place. 'answering questions on stackoverflow' becomes just a placeholder.

It not hard to implement this using just Text, like this one:

```
Group {
                Text("I would like to spend ")
                    .foregroundColor(.primary) +
                Text("15 minutes")
                    .foregroundColor(.pink)
                    .underline() +
                Text(" on ")
                    .foregroundColor(.primary) +
                Text("answering questions on stackoverflow")
                    .foregroundColor(.teal)
                    .underline() +
                Text(" each ")
                    .foregroundColor(.primary) +
                Text("weekday")
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                    .underline()
            }
```

But in such case there is no way to add interactivity, like taps and Text input.

The other way can be probably handled with Markdown?

Thanks for advance.

[image]

Comment: You want to be able to edit the "answering questions on stack overflow" part *in place*? Or is it fine to have a separate text field show up?

Comment: I would like to do it in place

Comment: I don't think this can be done in pure SwiftUI then. You'd probably need a `UITextView`, at least.

Comment: @Sweeper yep, using good old ranges and TextView delegates

Comment: As soon as I use onTapGesture on those Texts it gives me a compile error: The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time. Why is that the case?

Comment: @MatBuompy as you can see, I used "+" symbol to concatenate Text() structs into one. Text struct inherits from Equatable and Sendable. When you start adding onTapGesture to any of the Text() structs, it becomes any View object. Compiler does not know that this type can be concatenated. Probably this is the answer.

Comment: @PeteStreem Thank you for the explanation. It's pretty clear and makes sense.